# How to measure vertical plane surface (visible in camera) using ARKit-Scenekit before placing objects?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, distance, arkit

I want to measure the vertical plane surface to find whether it fits the object that I am going to place. For example if i am going to place a node (with a fixed size) in a room using  ARKit,

First, I want to detect if that room surface is sufficient or not to place my node by measuring the surface area (width and height etc.).

Second, if the user tries to place it without sufficient place, I should not allow him to place the cot and show him an error message.

I am using ARKit Scenekit in order to achieve this and I am new to AR and Scenekit. I need to know if this is doable, and if so how to achieve it.